# Are there any contemporary continental studies based on linking the philosophy of language to science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, philosophy-of-language

I guess verificationism may be a philosophy of language: the idea that

> t[o know the meaning of a scientific proposition](https://www.jstor.org/stable/495829?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)... is to know what
>   would be evidence for that proposition

Are there more contemporary intersections between philosophy of language and science?

I'm especially interested in verbose continental work: so please cite up to four books etc. (arguments, chapters, articles, positions) which are based in work with both the philosophy of language and science.

Comment: I think you should mention continental in your title since the main such interfaces are in analytic philosophy.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing more connections, and I do think that they're there - I have some ideas myself; that the question can't be answered or even be given hints shows a possibly narrow pool of expertise in the community.

Comment: I want to strongly endorse the point @MoziburUllah has made: I have the feeling that often enough close votes are made, because the question isn't *conceived* as answerable. But that often seems to be a problem of lacking expertise in fields that are perfectly able to answer these question. A little more humbleness would be good. (I do not intend to attack Keelan or Joseph in person here, it is more of a general observation within the last weeks).

Comment: This is a list question ("are there more ...") and can be answered as broadly or narrowly as one wants. In the end, intersections can be drawn between any two fields depending how free one wants to be with the term 'intersection'. It would be preferable to ask something more specific.

Comment: are open ended questions against the rules @Keelan

Comment: I don't think it's possible to strictly define 'rules' for what questions are 'allowed', it is always a judgement call. I explained my reasoning in the previous comment.

Comment: i don't really get what you mean. i don't want to argue about it, but surely every question that should be closed is against the rules. which rules do open ended / list questions break? seems like it's as narrow as it is broad

Comment: There's Putnams [Philosophy of language & science](https://www.jstor.org/stable/495829?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents); not continental, but looks quite useful; he starts with verificationism; Stenger might be another useful resource; personally, I'm intrigued by the role of metaphor in science, which of course is a literary term; perhaps too, allegory and analogy.

Comment: What I mean is that there is not a specific set of rules that we look at when seeing if questions fit on this site. I explained why I think this is too broad in my earlier comment. No, you will not find exactly these reasons in the help centre. I do believe they fit into its spirit though. Even the vaguest links between science and philosophy of languages could constitute an answer, so it is not clear when an answer deals with enough intersections, or what is a good answer to this question.